'Conflicting' threads?
I am trying to understand threading and if/when its use is the most appropriate in context of a project I am working on. I am running this on a RPi 4, using python.
I have a fairly large script, two elements of the script are causing a problem in particular. Each produces the desired outcome in isolation:

Connecting to a BLE device, write data to a file (SCAN). For info, this script uses asyncio
A MPU6050, write data to a file (GYRO). For info, this script includes a thread

The larger script runs the necessary function for 1 & 2 at different times, when called through a GUI.
The current method adopted (using PYSIMPLEGUI), has a (2 sec) timeout event that triggers the GYRO read/write. Through a different GUI window, the SCAN should run, again triggered by a timeout event.
This is where my current problem sits. The GYRO will run quite happily, as soon a the SCAN is called, an exception occurs with bleak. (Operation already in progress)
I have error traced the problem back to an initial thread in the GYRO script. Running the SCAN script beforehand GOOD, anytime after BAD!
Using a simple thread script as below, 1 & 2 play nicely. Using threading to call 1 & 2 independently does not help.
gyro = threading.Thread(target=gyro_thread_function, args=(1,))
gyro.start()
gyro.join()
scan = threading.Thread(target=scan_thread_function, args=(1,))
scan.start()
scan.join()

Is threading the correct approach to take if the two routines are run at different times? To my mind they appear to be conflicting.

Starting and immediately joining a thread will not give you any concurrency.

If you're starting threads each time, you may want to consider keeping them running rather than paying the startup cost.  Not sure if it would matter, but there are timer APIs in PSG to provide timers with less drift/better latency than a read timeout.  For me, logging with timestamps and dat a like buffer levels helps to debug this kind of problem so I can see what's happening when, where latencies are, and if CPU-bound.
